# Angular 2 : How to design Modules and Components

Tags: angular

I would have the following structure for page A in my application.

```
Directory view 
  --page
  --page
  --page
  --page
Directory view 
  --page
  --page
  --page
  --page
Directory view 
  --page
  --page
  --page
  --page
```

I have created a module for Page A. This module will be loaded in the app.module.ts.

My question is : Should i create modules for Directory and page both and include these in the module for page A or should I only create components which are used inside the component of page A while the component of page A is only exported by the module for page A.

Personally i think approach 2 is more suitable as all the components would be wrapped inside one module. But the concern here is that then using this approach then, the best way would be to create folders inside the page A folder to wrap the component files for the directory and page separately.

Comment: Did you read the style guide? https://angular.io/styleguide#!#app-structure-and-angular-modules

Comment: yup ... i had . found the exact data i needed . thanks ... approach 2 it is